# meteor internationalization with tab-i18n on cordova android-device

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, internationalization

I am trying to get tab-i18n running local with my android-device.

I start meteor with 

`meteor run android-device --mobile-server="http://local_network_server_ip_address:3000/"`

On my pc, in the browser the tab-i18n functions are running but not on the android device.

Any hint or advice?

Comment: Any solutions for this issue already? I'm having the same problems. `tap:i18n` is working in the browser, but not on mobile.

Comment: Nevermind, I got this working using the `tap:i18n-bundler` package. You do need to specify the `cdn_path`, as is shown in the [readme](https://github.com/TAPevents/i18n-bundler). It does not work without.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile development, you need both the `tap:i18n` and the `tap:i18n-bundler` packages. Then follow the [instructions](https://github.com/TAPevents/i18n-bundler) for the `tap:i18n-bundler` package. More specifically, you need to specify the `cdn_path`.